# Removing non- printable data from string

Tags: python, string

I have a string `final line` as

```
['0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.070802847389,0.0,0.0,', '0.0,0.0,0.169140135429,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,', '0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0261263917462,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0261263917462,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,', '0.0961428138228,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,', '']
```

I have to remove last non printable data `''` from the string.

Comment: Actually, it *is* printable

Comment: Is this a Python list? `final line` is no Python identifier. Please post some real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
list_name.remove('')
```

in this case.
If you want to delete last element from a list:

```
list_name = list_name[:-1]
```

or

```
list_name.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is called `final_line`,

`final_line.remove('')` should remove `''` from list